# OpenCL : pass two String to kernel, return nothing

Tags: c++, opencl

I'd like to pass two String to an OpenCL kernet, and print text directly from it.

So far, i have this :

```
int main(void) {
    Context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU);
    static const unsigned elements = 1000;

    vector<string> dataA;
    for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
        dataA.push_back("a");
    }

    vector<string> dataB;
    for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
        dataB.push_back("b");
    }

    Buffer a(begin(dataA), end(dataA), true, false);
    Buffer b(begin(dataB), end(dataB), true, false);

    Program addProg(R"d(
        kernel
        void add(string a, string b) {
            unsigned idx = get_global_id(0);
            c[idx] = 2.0;
        }
    )d", true);

    auto add = make_kernel<Buffer, Buffer>(addProg, "add");
    add(EnqueueArgs(elements), a, b);


    system("pause");
}
```

This code crashes at runtime without explanation.

How can i debug this, and is it possible to print text from withn the kernel and display it on screen ?

Comment: Which OpenCL platform are you using? Can you show the kernel code? Have you tried catching any exceptions thrown from the OpenCL C++ bindings to get a useful error message?

Comment: Agree with jprice. Additionally, to your question: The only possible way to print data to string from CL is using extensions (like: cl_amd_printf)

Comment: I use the OpenCL version bundled with the AMD SDK. 
The kernel is on the code i linked the line starting with Program addPr...
I can't get any exception, it seems like they aren't thrown or something, i just get this window http://i.imgur.com/Vhj9uUD.png

Comment: That window definitely shows that a `cl::Error` exception is being thrown, which you should be able to catch. Your kernel code seems to be referencing a `c` variable that isn't defined. Also, I don't believe that `string` is a valid data-type (although I've never used AMD's C++ Kernel language extension). You should try just using `char*`.

Comment: I knew string would be a problem. However, i don't think i can create a vector of char*, so i'm gonna have a problem right ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? What are you trying to print?

Comment: I need to do calculation based on characters value (some boring math stuff). I use OpenCL because the calculation process is really long, and i need to print the result of every steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so it sounds like you want to pass an array/vector of strings to a kernel, and have each work-item in the kernel process a different string. You can't really do this with the STL vector and string classes since these don't work inside OpenCL kernels, so the easiest thing to do would be to instead use a flattened C array of characters (with all of the strings in one array).

I've modified your program below to do this. Basically, we set the maximum number of characters any string will need (assuming you know what this is) in the `charsPerString` variable. We then allocate an array with `elements*charsPerString` characters, and initialise the strings with a single character as you were doing. The i-th string starts at index `i*charsPerString`. We can then pass this to the kernel as a single buffer.

The kernel then has each work-item print out the first character in each of the two strings it is passed using `printf`, computing the start of its string in the same way as above.

I've also added the typical C++ error checking approach with exceptions, which will display any of the OpenCL errors that might occur. I've tested this on my own laptop, and it works, printing out:

```
0 has characters a and b
1 has characters a and b
2 has characters a and b
3 has characters a and b
4 has characters a and b
```

(which is what we would expect).

Hopefully you should be able to extend this to your own use cases.

```
#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cl;
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
  try {
    Context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU);
    static const unsigned elements = 1000;

    static const unsigned charsPerString = 16;

    char *dataA = new char[elements*charsPerString];
    for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
      dataA[i*charsPerString] = 'a';
    }

    char *dataB = new char[elements*charsPerString];
    for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
      dataB[i*charsPerString] = 'b';
    }

    Buffer a(dataA, dataA+elements*charsPerString, true, false);
    Buffer b(dataB, dataB+elements*charsPerString, true, false);

    Program addProg(R"d(
        constant unsigned charsPerString = 16;
        kernel
        void add(global char *a, global char *b) {
            unsigned idx = get_global_id(0);
            printf("%d has characters %c and %c\n",
                   idx, a[idx*charsPerString], b[idx*charsPerString]);
        }
    )d");

    try {
      addProg.build();
    }
    catch (Error err) {
      if (err.err() == CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE) {
        cout << "OpenCL build failure:" << endl;
        cout << addProg.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(Device::getDefault());
      }
      throw err;
    }

    addProg.build();

    auto add = make_kernel<Buffer, Buffer>(addProg, "add");
    add(EnqueueArgs(elements), a, b);
    CommandQueue::getDefault().finish();

    delete[] dataA;
    delete[] dataB;
  }
  catch (Error err) {
    cerr << "ERROR: " << err.what() << " (" << err.err() << ")" << endl;
  }

  system("pause");
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, exactly was i was expecting. Thank you ;)